# How can i create a 3D modeling app? What resources i will required?

Tags: mobile-application, 3d-modelling, photogrammetry

I want to create a application which converts 2d-images/video into a 3d model. While researching on it i found out similar application like Trnio, Scann3D, Qlone,and few others(Though few of them provide poor output 3D model). I also find out about a technology launched by the microsoft research called mobileFusion which showed the same vision i was hoping for my application but these apps were non like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a 3D modelling app is complex task, and achieving it to a high standard requires a lot of studying. To point you in the right direction, you most likely want to perform something called [Structure-from-Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion)(SfM) or [Simultaneous Localization and Mapping](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=_beNW4XkJcqNgAb-96bABA&q=simultaneous+localization+and+mapping&oq=simultaneous+loca&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l3j0i20i263k1j0l6.1052.8341.0.9073.34.30.0.0.0.0.179.2894.18j10.28.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..18.16.1464...35i39k1j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i22i30k1.0.TVSV6wSeuoI) (SLAM).

If you want to program this yourself [OpenCV](https://opencv.org) is a good place to start if you know C++ or Python. A typical pipeline involves; feature extraction and matching, camera pose estimation, triangulation and then optimised using a bundle adjustment. All pipelines for SfM and SLAM follow these general steps (with exceptions of course). All of these steps are possible is OpenCV although Googles Ceres Solver is an excellent open-source bundle adjustment. SfM generally goes onto dense matching which is where you get very dense point clouds which are good for creating meshes. A free open-source pipeline for this is [OpenSfM](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM). Another good source for tools is [OpenMVG](https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG) which has all of the tools you need to make a full pipeline.

SLAM is similar to SfM, however, has more of a focus on real-time application and less on absolute accuracy. Applications for this is more centred around robotics where a robot wants to know where it is relative to its environment, but it not so concerned on absolute accuracy. The top SLAM algorithms are [ORB-SLAM](http://webdiis.unizar.es/~raulmur/orbslam/) and [LSD-SLAM](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam). Both are open-source and free for you to implement into your own software.

So really it depends what you want... SfM for high accuracy, SLAM for real-time. If you want a good 3D model I would recommend using existing algorithms as they are very good.

The best commercial software in my opinion... [Agisoft Photoscan](http://www.agisoft.com). If you can make anything half as good as this i'd be very impressed. To answer your question what resources will you require. In my opinion, python/c++ skills, the ability to google well and a spare time to read up on photogrammetry and SfM properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I  know the basics of python and c++, so I think I will go with python coz it's easy to use. I have already start studying about photogrammetry . And I will start looking for SfM. Again thanks for the help. I will update questions if I will require help again.